# Filter all queries based on url parameters

Tags: django

I have in a Django project all my urls based on the following syntax:

```
/ID_PROGRAM/ID_PROJECT/blablabla
```

I would like by default that all my queries have the following filters:

```
.filter(program=ID_PROGRAM).filter(project=ID_PROJECT)
```

How can I apply these filters automatically to all my queries? My idea was to define a new `manager`. But is the `manager` able to access to the `url parameters`? I this the best way to do?

To complet the question, I want to enrich all my queries without having to pass explicitly the view parameters to the manager.

Answer (score 2):

You could have just tried it to see if it works.

Yes, managers do accept parameters

```
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def my_filters(self, id_prog, id_proj):
        return super(MyModelManager, self).get_query_set().filter(program=id_prog, project=id_proj)
```

and in the views:

```
MyModelManager.objects.my_filters(id_prog, id_proj)
```

Documentation on [custom managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers)

Comment: In your suggestion, you have to explicitly provide the parameters to the manager. I would like to enrich the query without having to give the information explicitly.

Comment: If you were to filter based on dynamic criteria, you have to provide parameters somehow right?

Comment: Sure, but is-there a way to get them in another way like with a session or a `context singleton`?

Comment: You could use a session, but IMO, the effort is more because you would have to pass in request in the context of the manager. Keep it simple. It is quite straightforward. Another thing you could do is inject these variables through a middleware. But is it worth the effort? Python promotes "Explicit is better than implicit"

Answer (score 1):

> Python promotes "Explicit is better than implicit"

*karthikr* is almost right, but you can also use:

1 - decorator above your function. Decorator will get args from url and put objects to any variable

2 - write mixin and aply it to view. Mixin will get args from url at overriden `dispatch` and save filter result to `self.custom_context`. Override `get_context_data` to merge contexts.

Comment: I understand the point "Explicit is better than implicit" but if one person omit the decorator/filter/mixin, we will have an issue and it's tedious to write a test on this point for each view. We lost the "don't repeat yourself" principle and expose the code to potential issues.

Comment: @Julio so.. decorator is bad, mixin is bad and manager is bad? hm... i don't know any other way to get parameters automatically.